# django - update date automatically after a value change

Tags: python, django, datetime, python-3.x

In the following django model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

I want the pub_date field to be automatically updated with the current date, every time the published field changes to True.

What is the smart way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All answers were useful, but I finally did it this way:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.published and self.pub_date is None:
        self.pub_date = timezone.now()
    elif not self.published and self.pub_date is not None:
        self.pub_date = None
    super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 24):

You want to add the auto_now field and set it to True. This will update with the current timestamp each time you update the model.

```
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date_published', auto_now=True)
```

You can read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield)

---

**Edit**

Sorry you really just want to change the timestamp when the value of published is set to True. A really easy way to do this is to get the original value of the model and then override the save method so that it gets updated when it is set to True. Here is what you add to your code:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._published = self.published

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self._published and self.published:
            self.pub_date = django.timezone.now()
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I don't want to update the timestamp every time I update the model. I just want to update it, only when the published field changes to True.

Answer (score 12):

If you are setting the object as published in the Django admin, a nice way to do this is to override the [`save_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method of your model admin class.

```
from datetime import datetime

from django.contrib import admin


class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if obj.published and 'published' in form.changed_data
            obj.pub_date = datetime.now()
            obj.save()

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

If you are setting the published flag elsewhere, then you can override the `save()` method, or use the `pre_save` signal. This isn't as elegant, because it's harder to tell whether the `published` flag has changed. I think you need to re-fetch the object from the database to check.

Comment: Very useful! I also added this condition: `if obj.pub_date is None:`, because I didn't want to overwrite the old published date if the user publishes, unpublishes and publishes a post.

Comment: @Flimm checking `if obj.pub_date is None` might be the right thing for you. However, the original question explicity said *every* time the published field changes to True.

Comment: Fair enough. (I'll delete this comment.)

Answer (score 9):

the following only changes your pub_date if published has been modified from False to True:

```
from datetime import datetime

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.old_published = self.published

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.published and self.old_published != self.published:
        self.pub_date = datetime.now()
    super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I like this, but what if I publish, unpublish and then publish again the object?

Comment: @Ilias95 do you want to set the pub_date to empty if you un-publish?

Comment: It probably doesn't matter.

Comment: A "self.old_published = self.published" just before calling super will do the job. Edit it you wish. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `publish()` method:

```
def publish(self):
    self.published = True
    self.pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.save()
```

Comment: I would prefer to be able to just check the appropriate check box in the django admin panel and have nothing else to do. Is it possible to call this method from there?

Comment: @Ilias95 you'll need to combine this answer with the answer Alasdair gave below.

Answer (score 0):

*just Override Update method*

```
from django.utils import timezone


class Vehicle(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'updated': timezone.now})
        super().update(*args, **kwargs)

        return self
```

Answer (score 0):

A really tricky easy way to do it, is by actually getting the query after you update it, and invoking `save()` on it, this all happens in the view, I will create the simplest implementation of a view that receive a post request:

```py
def update_published_view(request,pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       models.MyModel.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(published=request.POST.get('is_published','')
       my_model_instance = models.MyModel.objects.get(pk=pk) # the trick here is to access 
#the instance after it is updated and then invoke `save()` 
#on the query to actually update the date field
       my_model_instance.save()
return render(request,'somepage.html')
```

and don't forget to set `auto_now` to `True` in `pub_date` field in `MyModel` model.