# django admin model field not update

Tags: python, django

I use Django Admin to add data, but the today field won't update to current time, always show django started time.

model.py:

```html
class Post(models.Model):
    today = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
    date = models.CharField(max_length=8,default=datetime.now())
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

[image link of screenshot to show my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QS8TX.png)

Comment: The 'today' field will only be set when the application is started.... same with the default field on your 'date' field. You should pass in the function to the default field (ie, remove the brackets). I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the today field though...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django - update date automatically after a value change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858418/django-update-date-automatically-after-a-value-change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today needs to be a DateField. I assume you're trying to add only date not datetime, given your strftime formatting. Also, date should not be a CharField but rather a DateField or DateTimeField.

Furthermore, you need to use add_now or auto_add_now, depending on whether you want the value to be updated everytime the model is saved or only on creation, [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#datefield)

I imagine that the following is what you're trying to do:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    today = models.DateField(add_now=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_add_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `models.DateTimeField()`. It should be:

`today = models.DateTimeField()`